# Python: Append to dictionary from a zip

Tags: python, dictionary, zip

Lets say I have the following list such as `[key,value, key,value, key,value]`
and I want to turn it into a dictionary which looks like:
`{key:value, key:value, key:value}`

I have tried

```
dict(zip(mydict[::2], mydict[1::2]))
```

However, the original values for one of the keys keeps being overwritten. How can I change this so it appends to the dictionary if the key already exists?

Comment: It doesn't. Are you sure that there are no repeated keys?

Comment: oh, there repeated keys, how do I  keep them from overwriting each other and just append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding then.  You cannot have repeated keys inside a dictionary.  One will overwrite the other.

```
 [in] >>> d = dict([('x',3),('x',4)])
 [in] >>> print(d)
[out] >>> {'x': 4}
```

Maybe you're thinking of a defaultdict

```
 [in] >>> from collections import defaultdict
 [in] >>> d = defaultdict(list)
 [in] >>> for k,v in [('x',3),('x',4)]:
      >>>     d[k].append(v)
 [in] >>> print(d)
[out] >>> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'x': [3, 4]})
```