# Matching multiple patterns in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like that:

```
s = "[A] text [B] more text [C] something ... [A] hello"
```

basically it consists of `[X] chars` and I am trying to get the text "after" every `[X]`.

I would like to yield this dict (I don't care about order):

```
mydict = {"A":"text, hello", "B":"more text", "C":"something"}
```

I was thinking about a regex but I was not sure if that is the right choice because in my case the order of [A], [B] and [C] can change, so this string is valid too:

```
s = "[A] hello, [C] text [A] more text [B] something"
```

I don't know how to properly extract the string. Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: you are right. sorry. Edited.

Comment: Did you try to use re.findall to find each "[X] chars" in your input string, then to use re.match to retrieve X and chars ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is quite what you're looking for but it fails with duplicates

```
s = "[A] hello, [C] text [A] more text [B] something"

results = [text.strip() for text in re.split('\[.\]', s) if text]

letters = re.findall('\[(.)\]', s)

dict(zip(letters, results))

{'A': 'more text', 'B': 'something', 'C': 'text'}
```

Since the output looks like this:

```
In [49]: results
Out[49]: ['hello,', 'text', 'more text', 'something']

In [50]: letters
Out[50]: ['A', 'C', 'A', 'B']
```

To solve for duplicate you could do something like....

```
mappings = {}

for pos, letter in enumerate(letters):
    try:
        mappings[letter] += ' ' + results[pos]
    except KeyError:
        mappings[letter] = results[pos]
```

which gives: `{'A': 'hello, more text', 'B': 'something', 'C': 'text'}`

**UPDATE**

Or even better you could look at using a default dict: as shown here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091911/python-append-to-dictionary-from-a-zip)

Comment: I updated as I noticed the OP wanted to join the dup values in his dict.

Comment: This is good. What if the string would be `s="arbitrary text [A] abc [B] fff [C]..."` Then "arbitrary text" would be extracted as well. How to get rid of it? Another thing: what if `[X]` is `[CAR]` or `[ CAR ]` (I want to remove whitespace after/before)

Comment: Getting `[X]` and `[CAR]` is just a matter of changing `'\[(.)\]'` to `'\[(\w)\]'` to match words. If you want to get rid of leading results you could just cheat and compare `len(results)` and `len(letters)` then pop items accordingly

Answer (score 1):

> Expected output: `mydict = {"A":"text, hello", "B":"more text", "C":"something"}`

```
import re

s = "[A] text [B] more text [C] something ... [A] hello"

pattern = r'\[([A-Z])\]([ a-z]+)'

items = re.findall(pattern, s)

output_dict = {}

for x in items:
    if x[0] in output_dict:
        output_dict[x[0]] = output_dict[x[0]] + ', ' + x[1].strip()
    else:
        output_dict[x[0]] = x[1].strip()

print(output_dict)
```

`>>> {'A': 'text, hello', 'B': 'more text', 'C': 'something'}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```or-tag-here
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
s = "[A] text [B] more text [C] something ... [A] hello"
d = dict()
for x in re.findall(r"\[[^\]+]\][^\[]*",s):
    m = re.match(r"\[([^\]*])\](.*)",x)

    if not d.get(m.group(1),0):
        #Key doesn't already exist
        d[m.group(1)] = m.group(2)
    else:
        d[m.group(1)] = "%s, %s" % (d[m.group(1)], m.group(2))

print d
```

Prints:

```
{'A': ' text ,  hello', 'C': ' something ... ', 'B': ' more text '}
```