# Python dictionary print all values for all keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I have two python lists:

```
keys=[1,2,2,3,2,3]
values=['apple','book','pen','soccer','paper','tennis']
```

The "keys" are cluster ID list for the corresponding words in "values" list. I wish to print key-value pairs using

```
keys=[1,2,2,3,2,3]
values=['apple','book','pen','soccer','paper','tennis']

dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
for key, value in dictionary.items() :
    print (key, value)
```

But it only prints

```
1 apple
2 paper
3 tennis
```

What I actually want is to get all values for all keys like this

```
1 [apple]
2 [book,pen,paper]
3 [soccer,tennis]
```

I know that my current code should logically print the first output as keys are unique. But how can I change it so that it will print all values for all keys? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Append to dictionary from a zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091911/python-append-to-dictionary-from-a-zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools`:

```
import itertools
keys=[1,2,2,3,2,3]
values=['apple','book','pen','soccer','paper','tennis']
final_data = {a:[i[0] for i in b] for a, b in [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(zip(values, keys), key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])]}
```

Output:

```
{1: ['apple'], 2: ['book', 'pen', 'paper'], 3: ['soccer', 'tennis']}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from collections import defaultdict

keys=[1,2,2,3,2,3]
values=['apple','book','pen','soccer','paper','tennis']

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    d[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like what you want is a mapping from one key to multiple values, one way to accomplish it would be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

keys=[1,2,2,3,2,3]
values=['apple','book','pen','soccer','paper','tennis']

for tuple in zip(keys, values):
    d[tuple[0]].append(tuple[1])

print(d)  # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['apple'], 2: ['book', 'pen', 'paper'], 3: ['soccer', 'tennis']})
```

Answer (score 1):

pure python also works

```
keys=[1,2,2,3,2,3]
values=['apple','book','pen','soccer','paper','tennis']

d = dict(zip(keys, [[] for _ in keys]))  # dict w keys, empty lists as values

for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    d[k].append(v)

d
Out[128]: {1: ['apple'], 2: ['book', 'pen', 'paper'], 3: ['soccer', 'tennis']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two method :

If you want you can use default dict as many already have been suggested :

> Data is :

```
keys=[1,2,2,3,2,3]
values=['apple','book','pen','soccer','paper','tennis']
```

> Method: 1

```
import collections


d=collections.defaultdict(list)

for i in zip(keys,values):
    d[i[0]].append(i[1])

print(d)
```

> output:

```
{1: ['apple'], 2: ['book', 'pen', 'paper'], 3: ['soccer', 'tennis']}
```

Or if you want to develop your own logic without importing any external module then you can try:

```
result={}
for i in zip(keys,values):
    if i[0] not in result:
        result[i[0]]=[i[1]]
    else:
        result[i[0]].append(i[1])

print(result)
```

output:

```
{1: ['apple'], 2: ['book', 'pen', 'paper'], 3: ['soccer', 'tennis']}
```

Comment: `for k, v in zip(keys, values):` is more readable to me, nested indexing is ugly when suggestive labels can be used instead: `result[k]=[v]`